# UX approaches for re-usable and configurable dashboards

Tags: dashboard, customisation, templates

Sorry for unclear post title, can't think of the succinct term which defines this problem. Any suggestions appreciated!

I'm looking for some good examples of different approaches that applications take towards the handling of dashboard templates which are re-usable and also user-configurable.

As an example, you want to analyse various metrics related to Tennis players. You load up a player's profile and are shown the default 'template' of analysis, eg:

1. last 10 matches results
2. ranking over time
3. earnings over time

Earnings are not of interest to you, so you replace it with a graph related to his serve accuracy. So now you are viewing an 'edited' version of the base template.

The thorny issues arising from this kind of action are what I'm interested in and would love to see some examples of applications that handle this type of scenario. I just can't think where to look! Any ideas much appreciated.

The issues I'm thinking about are things like:

- approaches to saving the changes you made either to update the base
  template or save as a new one
- optionality around having an edited template now show up as your default template when you next load up a player... or not
- discarding changes and reverting back to base
- locked admin defined templates versus user flexible ones
- how applications indicate/make transparent to users the way this all works
- Deleting / management of templates
- Sharing of templates between different users,
  and issues of editing them in these cases
- etc etc!

Many thanks for any ideas where I can look to see apps that address this kind of design problem

P.S - I know context is king and there are no one size fits all solutions. I'm not looking for answers, I just want to immerse myself in some different approaches before I decide what is best for my particular product.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example to share which shows one way of making things work. It's based on the email templates feature which Indeed.com portal has for recruiters to contact potential candidates for hiring purposes. Due to sensitive nature of content I can't post screenshots here.

Basically, what Indeed does is to start off with an empty template for new users - you are free to write anything in the letter/ pitch to potential candidates and it allows you to save what you have written as a template.

For subsequent similar group of potential candidates that you approach, this default template will load by itself.

And when you approach the second or third group of candidates where you realise you need to re-tailor the message content, you can tweak the message and save it as a new template on the same page.

After saving the new template, subsequent attempts to contact potential candidates will always load the new template as the default template for the user.

To revert to the previous template(s), you can select from a dropdown box listing the templates saved so far, and the page will reload itself. In addition, there is a separate screen for users to manage the list of templates they have.

Hope this helps!